# Content won't expand into a div with a min-width and max-width set - width always stuck at min

Tags: css, styling

I have a menu container that contains `<a>` tags with various lengths of strings.

When I give my menu container the following CSS, my menu is always statically set to the min-width (in this case, `200px`). I want longer strings to push out until the max-width. If I don't set a min-width, The container becomes very small because of the `nav-bar`s width of `50px`. `navbar` is in another React file with a separate CSS file. How can I detach the menu from being controlled by the nav's width?

*the content only expands past it's set min-width with if the `<a>` contains a string with no spaces/word-breaks.

Here is a codepen with an example of the behavior: https://codepen.io/vee1234/pen/omQxWP

**CSS**

```
  .nav-bar {
     width: 50px;
    }

    .hover-menu {
      display: inline-block
      min-width: 200px;
      max-width: 400px;
      width: 100%
      position: relative;
      left: 40px;
    }

    .link a {
      line-height: 35px;
      color: #d8d8d8;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
```

**REACT**

```
 <Nav className={navbar}>   
   <Menu>
    <div className={hover-menu}>
      <div className={links}>
        <a>some text</a>
        <a>some longer text that never expands past 200px</a>
      </div>
      </Menu>
    </Nav>
 </div>
```

Comment: I just tried this in a codepen and it acted as you are saying you want it to... What is your css for the links?

Comment: having the same thing happen, works outside of my environment as intended. will add full CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.link a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 35px;
  color: #d8d8d8;
  height: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

I think the problem you were having was that all your links were in line. I hope I'm right in assuming that you meant for them to be stacked... If so, making the `a` tags display block while giving the menu container an inline-block display with the min and max renders the menu as described.

Comment: same issue :(, with that exact CSS - the container is always set at `200px`

Comment: Ah I just figured out, a parent element in another file has a width set to `50px`... not sure why its effecting this menu.

Comment: If I expand the parent to larger than min-width, the menu expands. whats the best way to get `menu` to ignore another files css?

Comment: You could give the `menu` another class then specify your new width with `!important` and you would only have to use this rule where you want to change the width of the `menu`

Comment: im not sure I understand @CliffRono - I want the menu to be at minimum 200px, but flexible width to expand up to 400px. Are you saying give those `min-width` and `max-widths` an `!important` flag?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can prevent the `hover-menu` from conforming to the width constraints of the parent by using positions. In this case, the `menu` tag will have

```
position:relative;
```

and the class `hover-menu` will have

```
position:absolute;
left:0;
```

and you might as well specify your other css rules on the `hover-menu`.

Comment: here is an example of the problem: https://codepen.io/vee1234/pen/omQxWP